# undefined reference to `_setjmp' building SFML

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, undefined-reference, building

I'm building SFML for MinGW as explained in the official tutorials. I'm using the latest MinGW from WinLibs, for 64x systems. I followed the tutorial exactly how it was, with SFML 2.6 from GitHub, but when I run "mingw32-make" to build, I get, after a list of "Building CXX object...", these two errors:

```
h:/winlibs_64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/jayok/Downloads/SFML-2.6.x/SFML-2.6.x/extlibs/libs-mingw/x64/libfreetype.a(sfnt.c.obj):sfnt.c:(.text+0x5614): undefined reference to `_setjmp'
h:/winlibs_64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/jayok/Downloads/SFML-2.6.x/SFML-2.6.x/extlibs/libs-mingw/x64/libfreetype.a(smooth.c.obj):smooth.c:(.text+0x77a): undefined reference to `_setjmp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src\SFML\Graphics\CMakeFiles\sfml-graphics.dir\build.make:602: lib/sfml-graphics-2.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:307: src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeFiles/sfml-graphics.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:155: all] Error 2
```

Comment: `setjmp()` is part of the C standard but requires `#include <setjmp.h>`.  Check if these sources indeed call `setjmp()` and have this include not excluded by some `#ifdef`.  The compiler (more precisely the linker) command should not require `lc`, but you could try and add it to `LDFLAGS` of the makefile.  Just some ideas.

Comment: Checking every source file and the relative included ones is a bit impratical to me. About the latest suggestion: could you explain how to do it? I'm not very expert on makefiles. Anyway, seems strange that the official tutorial leads to these two errors, which I couldn't find anywhere on the internet, too

Comment: You only need to check the two source files that cause the error: `sfnt.c` and `smooth.c`.  Did you open the makefile and look for `LDFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`?